# Xamarin rest api

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, xamarin-binding

Binding does not work in my code. what's wrong in this code?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("uri link"));
string jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
RootObject item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
titles.ItemsSource =item.ToString();
```

XAML code

```
<ListView x:Name="titles" HasUnevenRows="False" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                           <Label Text="{Binding note}"/>
                       </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

class object:

```
public class Result
{
    public string note { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Mmmm, what is the problem?

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán i could not bind with object . when i compile the code the list view as empty so please help how can solve thiz

Comment: ItemsSource should be an IEnumerable<T>, you are just assigning it a string value

Comment: and, your binding path is "note" put there is no property named note in your model

Comment: @Jason you are setting just a string, you have to set IEnumerable<T> , if you set a simple list of string you don't need a item template, but if you have a list of object you have to create a template for the cell and set the properties for each control

Comment: you are not setting a list of anything, you are just assigning a single string value: titles.ItemsSource =item.ToString();

Comment: sorry!!! @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you bind the lable to the note, but you set the titles.ItemsSource to the RootObject. the RootObject class doesn't have note. note is in Result class.

and you can't set the itemsource like that.

I suggest you to do this

```
var listItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>(jsonstring);
titles.ItemsSource = l;
```

Comment: if i am going to try this code it shows some error :-- Cannot deserialize the current json object. To fix this error either change the json or json array. whats wrong in this code.

Comment: I think its because your jsonstring contains more than one instance of Result class. I mean it has more than one note property. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @MSjjD jsonnstring :  {
      "response": {
        "results": [
            {
                "Created By": "non_authenticated_user_live",
                "Created Date": "2018-03-05T08:34:04.631Z",
                "Modified Date": "2018-03-05T08:34:04.677Z",
                "note": "gmmrng",
                "_id": "1520238844627x475879674311727300",
                "_type": "custom.note"
            }

Comment: your jsonnstring in not complete.

Answer (score 1):

According to me are upto:

```
RootObject item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
```

and can you try this code also after the above line:

```
titles.ItemsSource =item.Responce. results;
```